# Make the code run faster without nested loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve assignment problem, the code I wrote takes extremely long to run. I think it's due to nested loop I used. Is there another way to rewrite the code to make it more efficient. 
The question I am trying to solve. Basically, starting at first element to compare with every element to its right. if it is larger than the rest, it will be "dominator". Then the second element to compare with every element to its right again. All the way to the last element which will be automatically become "dominator"

```
def count_dominators(items):
    if len(items) ==0:
        return len(items)
    else:
        k = 1
        for i in range(1,len(items)):
            for j in items[i:]:
                if items[i-1]>j:
                    k = k+1
                else:
                    k = k+0        
        return k
```

Comment: So its just returning how many elements are less than the first? You can take out your else statement... and just initialize k to be 0... before the first if statement.

Comment: Hi ShanerM, essentially, I need to start first element, then second, then third... so on. all the way to the last element

Comment: So are you trying to sort the array or just get how many elements are less than each element to the right of it?

Comment: Because, if you are trying to sort, you could just use a merge sort or something like that. I am not sure how big you are expecting items to be either. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexities-of-all-sorting-algorithms/

Comment: To get how many elements are greater than its right elements. The list should be very big. As I ran the test file it takes forever

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to check if each item is a "dominator", then take the length - you have to exclude the final one to avoid taking `max` of an empty list, then we add 1 because we know that the final one is actually a dominator.

```
num_dominators = len([i for i in range(len(items) - 1) if items[i] > max(items[i + 1:])]) + 1
```

This is nice because it fits on one line, but the more efficient (single pass through the list) way to do it is to start at the end and every time we find a new number bigger than any we have seen before, count it:

```
biggest = items[-1]
n = 1
for x in reversed(items):
   if x > biggest:
       biggest = x
       n+=1
return n
```

Comment: I actually never think about do it backward. Let me try it.

Comment: Hey Simon, it worked.. something new for me today. Need to use different perspective to look a question! Thank you